# Unreal Engine Telling Me To Download Visual Studio Even Though I Want To Use CLion

Tags: clion, unreal-engine4

I just downloaded Unreal Engine. I have been using CLion for a long time, and I heard that Unreal Engine has an option to use CLion, so I thought that I will use that. However, when I'm creating a new project it says "please install Visual Studio."[image] How can I make it detect CLion instead? If it means anything, I'm using the Cygwin compiler in CLion. Also, I didn't do/install anything extra, I thought it would detect CLion automatically. I don't have visual studio installed, but I thought that CLion works fine too.

Comment: I think that thread talks about using visual studio. Not sure the same can be applied to CLion.

Comment: Have you installed CLion plugin and specify it in settings?

Comment: @Maxim Banaev Where can I find install this plugin? What's it called?

Comment: In the UE. Open Edit menu -> Plugin -> Programming -> CLion.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use CLion as your editor btw. UE4 just needs the Visual Studio toolchain to be installed on your system in order for it work, as it uses the MSVC compiler. Hence the "No compiler was found" error.

Once you've got that installed, create the UE project then once you're inside the editor you can enable the CLion plugin by going to `Edit > Plugins` and search for `CLion` and enable it.

Next go to `Edit > Editor Preferences` and search for `code editor` then select `CLion` as your source code editor from the drop down box

[Editor Preferences | Source Code Editor dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVTQW.png)

Finally, restart the editor!